# First LSN and last LSN the same in transaction log backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

When restoring SQL Server Transaction Log files, I have noticed a number of log backups taken over night that have the same First and Last LSN.

Do these files have to be restored as part of the chain or can they be skipped?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction log is a serial record of all the transactions that have been performed against the database since the transaction log was last backed up.
So, if there were no changes in the database between transaction log backups the First and the Last LSN will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, they can be skipped.

The only-slightly-longer answer: the reason that the first and last LSNs are the same for those backups is because nothing happened in that time interval to incite change in the log. That said, they'll also take no time to restore, so you're probably better off just restoring them than trying to account for this edge case if and when you need to restore them. Remember - the best plan in a crisis situation is often the simplest.